# PCRE (php) regex, subpattern with + matches and with * doesn't?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I want to match and catch **all existing (if any)** `<style...</style>` blocks and **the inside of one** `<body..</body>` block inside a html document.
I thought this was simple, but I bump against something weird.
This was my guess for the whole regex:

```
/(<style[\s\S]+<\/style>)*[\s\S]*<body.*>([\s\S]+)<\/body>/i
```

It results into nothing.  So i broke it apart and these parts work:

```
/(<body.*>([\s\S]+)<\/body>)/i
/(<style[\s\S]+<\/style>)/i
```

And weirdest of all this first line works too, while the second results empty!

```
/(<style[\s\S]+<\/style>)+/i
/(<style[\s\S]+<\/style>)*/i
```

So, I guess the error is the difference between * and + after the subpattern.  Why?  And how do I solve this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You've got four problems:

First and second, you're using regular expressions to parse HTML.

Third, you're matching too much: You need at least to make some of the quantifiers lazy, i. e. use `.*?`, `[\s\S]*?` etc., or your regex will match everything up to the end of the line or the file, and then only backtrack as much as necessary to find the last possible matching tag.

Fourth, you've set yourself up for catastrophic backtracking by having repeated groups inside repeated groups, both of which have myriads of ways to match the same text.

As I understand your question, you want to match everything from the first `<style>` tag to the final `</body>` and capture all the `<style>` tags' contents and the `<body>` tag's contents. Right? Then try

```
/(<style[\s\S]+<\/style>)[\s\S]*?<body.*?>([\s\S]+)<\/body>/i
```

To capture each `<style>` block separately, you could try, for a maximum of four possible `<style>` blocks:

```
/(<style[\s\S]+?<\/style>)?\s*(<style[\s\S]+?<\/style>)?\s*(<style[\s\S]+?<\/style>)?\s*(<style[\s\S]+?<\/style>)?\s*<body.*?>([\s\S]+)<\/body>/i
```

if the `<style>` blocks are all adjacent and only separated by whitespace. Can you see why it's not a good idea to use regex for this?

Comment: Although your regex works it does not capture the style blocks independantly.  For example, if 2 style blocks come directly after eachother, your solution is ok, but if you would have some strings between thh style blocks, it includes it in the result, which I don't want. So, only the style blocks themselves.

Comment: That was written ambiguously. Let me give example: <style>xxx</style>yyy<style>zzz</style>.  Your solution gives me the yyy which I don't want.

Comment: You can't capture the `<style>` blocks independently. At least not in JavaScript; .NET has a feature that allows this, but most regex engines don't (unless you know beforehand how many repetitions there can be as a maximum). My solution matches from the very first to the very last `<style>` block which is the best you can do with JS regexes.

Comment: What if I say, there can be max. 4 style blocks?

Comment: And maybe "independantly" is not the right term. It may match in 1 catch, but without the yyy of my example.  (My knowledge doesn't go that far as to see if that is included in your last answer. Sorry if I missed that.)

Comment: Tim, your solutions with max 4 blocks does come very close, but doesn't work when No style block is present. Then it should still catch the body.

Comment: It works here even if there are zero style blocks; after all, everything before the `<body>` part of the regex is optional.

Comment: Strange.  I use php. Maybe that's the difference.  But still, can you explain why everything before body part is optional?  I thought that the repititor ? means "one time", not "zero or more"?  That's the one used for the style subpatterns, right or am I missing something? And that's exactly where my problem lies again then.

Comment: Tim? Any comments on the above?

Comment: `?` means "zero or one time(s)"; if applied to another quantifier it means "match as little as possible" (`.*` vs. `.*?`)